# Library - Removing / Customizing visible items from Properties form?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, library, properties

[image: screen capture]

I have a library (in SP 2013) where I need to customize the visible item properties.  What I actually need to do is remove some of the columns from the properties form.  I can easily do this if it were a LIST, but it seems my old tricks won't work in a LIBRARY.  There seems to be no InfoPath option, and when I went into SPD, and removed those lines of code from the table, I got an error every time the page tried to load.

Is there something I'm missing in Libraries?

Comment: When you say properties form, do you mean the new, display and edit item forms?

Comment: Can't you just hide columns from content type in order to make the columns hidden from properties forms.

Comment: Shashank - Yes.

Comment: Ganesh - See below.

Answer (score 0):

**OOTB Solution**:

In order to hide columns from all properties forms in SharePoint library, follow below steps:

1. Open the library and then library Settings.
2. Select Advanced settings.
3. Click Yes for “Allow management of content types” and then click OK.
4. From the list of content types on library settings page, select the content type where the column you want to hide appears, e.g. “Document”.
5. From the list of columns for the selected content type, select the column.
6. Select Hidden and click OK.

Check below article given for SharePoint list. The steps are same for library too:

[Changing Order / Hiding Columns in New / Edit Forms](https://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2008/12/02/changing-order-hiding-columns-in-new-edit-forms/amp/).

Comment: I've allowed management of content types.  When I try to hide the columns this way, I get the red NO symbol whenever I try to hover over the HIDDEN option.

Comment: Can you add any screenshot of this? Which column you want to hide? Is this a SharePoint OOTB column or the custom column you created?

Comment: This column is one I created, a Yes/No type.

Comment: If this is a custom column then you should be able to hide it from content type? Can you please add the screenshot of what red NO symbol your were seeing... Also, have you created this column as a site column or library column (created from library settings directly)?

Comment: See main question above for screen capture.  This was added as a library column.

Answer (score 0):

The solution lay in the fact that it was a YES/NO column type that I was trying to set as Hidden.  Apparently this could not be done.  However, when this column was deleted and replaced with a CHOICE column (with the same yes/no option), the column could then be hidden from the form.  This works.